# 12.04 To repair apt-get package manager

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, postgresql

I was installing PostgreSQL 9.4 and pgAdmin on my Ubuntu 12.04 and after that I needed to install Postgis extension for Postgres as well. Before the Postgis step all was fine. There I tried with compiling the source code as well as with `dpkg -i .deb` method to install and both gave an error about a file missing - **libpq-fe.h**. I found out it's in a **libpq-dev** package, so did `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`. This returned me that this package is already installed. Though a folder in which the file libpq-fe.h (and others) should be was empty. So my guess was to remove libpq-dev and install it again. I tried both with `sudo apt-get remove ...` and `sudo apt-get remove --purge ...`.

From here the package manager broke and right now any attempt to install a package (below Wine, just for example) or do a `sudo apt-get upgrade` returns:

```
adambo@adam-pc:~/Downloads/postgis-2.2.2$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.1.20-0ubuntu0.12.04) but 9.5.3-1.pgdg12.4+1 is to be installed
 postgresql-server-dev-9.4 : Depends: libpq-dev (>= 9.4~) but 9.1.20-0ubuntu0.12.04 is to be installed
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**What I've tried:**

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo apt-get clean`
- `sudo apt-get remove`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove`
- `sudo apt-get install -f`

Some returned regular results (or nothing), but some returned same as in `code` above.

I also tried to remove libpq-dev and libpq5 packages, but any attempt resulted in the `code` above again.

**But**  `sudo apt-get install -f` gives me:

```
adambo@adam-pc:~/Downloads/postgis-2.2.2$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpq-dev
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-doc-9.5
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpq-dev
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/228 kB of archives.
After this operation, 141 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue  [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libpq-dev:
 libpq-dev depends on libpq5 (= 9.1.20-0ubuntu0.12.04); however:
  Version of libpq5 on system is 9.5.3-1.pgdg12.4+1.
dpkg: error processing libpq-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 libpq-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**What could I do to at least restore apt-get functionality?**

Comment: Could you try sudo apt-get remove libpq-dev libpq5 postgresql-server-dev-9.4 and then sudo apt-get -f install.

Comment: first command returned same `E: Unmet dependencies` but longer since there were more packages. The `sudo apt-get -f install` returned very same as above. Seems like my `apt-get remove` is kind of locked.

Comment: Hmm. Have you added a PPA recently?

Comment: I added the PPA from Postgres site only, should be rather safe.  I think removing the libpq-dev package and installing it again could help, since the package is broken anyway (files not where they should be). The problem is the apt-get remove won't work

Comment: Please try sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libpq-dev libpq5 postgresql-server-dev-9.4

Comment: this command removed postgresql-server-dev-9.4, but the other two give `dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libpq-dev:` and `of libpq5:` and list packages that use these libs.  `Errors were encountered while processing: libpq-dev  libpq5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tries and fails I tried with **Aptitude** (fortunately installed already) and pressed **g** to install/remove/repair packages. There I followed what it proposed to remove and... Error disappeared. **libpq-dev** was removed. Though some of other packages I actually need were removed as well.

**Therefore I recommend it to people who are able to easily restore and reinstall missing packages.**

Answer (score 0):

When discovering that files from `libpq-dev` are missing, the command to run is:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpq-dev
```

This command leaves alone the dependent packages, contrary to `apt-get remove` which dragged you into a dependency mess.